# Run Time Error 1004 while using Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open an excel workbook, apply formula in cell B2 and downwards. So far so good. Then selecting the column B from down to top where I am getting the error. The code is given below:

```
Sub GetImportFileName()
    Dim Finfo As String
    Dim FilterIndex As Integer
    Dim Title As String
    Dim FileName As Variant
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

'    Set up list of file filters
    Finfo = "Excel 2007 Files (*.xls),*.xls," & _
    "Excel 2010 Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx,"

'     Set the dialog box caption
    Title = "Select a File to Import"
'     Get the filename
    FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Finfo, _
    FilterIndex, Title)
'     Handle return info from dialog box
    If FileName = False Then
        MsgBox "No file was selected."
    Else
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(FileName) 'New Workbook is open
    End If


  wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

  Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook


  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select

   Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
          'Range("B1").Select
          ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
          ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+""'""&RC[-1]&""',"""
          Selection.Copy
          Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
          :=False, Transpose:=False
          ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select
    Loop

    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select


    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select ' **Here I am getting the Run Time Error 1004**

'    Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

Can you please help me what is wrong with the code ?

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,

Prem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **Select** the populated part of column B starting from **B2,** then:

```
Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Select
```